# two loads during a redirect () ->route ()

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

so here I do an if to know or redirect my form but when I redirect()->route() I have a double reload of the page just when I submit the form. 
when i put the right url directly i only have one load can someone help me?

CONTROLLER

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
        $search = $request->search;
        if($request->search_choise == "num_customer"){
            return redirect()->route('show.customer', $search);
        }elseif($request->search_choise == "name"){
            return redirect()->route('table.customers', $search);
        }
}

public function show($id)
{
    $customer = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('customers.show', compact('customer'));
}
```

ROUTE

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'CustomersController@index', 'as' => 'index.customers']);
Route::post('/', ['uses' => 'CustomersController@search', 'as' => 'search.customers']);
Route::get('/details_client/{id}', ['uses' => 'CustomersController@show', 'as' => 'show.customer']);
```

MY CONSOLELOG WHEN POST MY FORM

```
Navigated to http://dev/details_client/6905
Navigated to http://dev/details_client/6905
```

MY CONSOLELOG WHEN GO http://dev/details_client/6905

```
Navigated to http://dev/details_client/6905
```

UPDATE

I only have that on chrome!

Have a good day!

Comment: Check your Middlewear. Sometimes there are two calls to $next($request) meant the route was being hit twice.

Comment: Do you have ads on your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here, restarting chrome does not work I had to shutdown all chrome processes and now no more problem I apologize for having bothered you.